# Filtering for only complete sets of years

Tags: r, filtering, panel

I have data on yield organized by State and County. Out of this data I want to retain only those counties providing complete years between 1970 to 2000.

The following code clears away some incomplete cases, however fails to omit all the cases- especially with a larger data set. The fake data

Some fake data:

## fake data

```
K <- 5 # number of rows set to NaN

df <- data.frame(state = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)),
                 county = rep(1:4, 5), yield = 100)

df[sample(1:20, K), 3] <- NaN
```

Current code:

```
df1 <- read.csv("gly2.csv",header=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(df1)


droprows_1 <- function(df, v1, v2, v3, value = 'x'){
  idx <- df[, v3] == value
  todrop <- df[idx, c(v1, v2)]; todrop # should have K rows missng
  todrop <- unique(todrop); todrop # but unique values could be less

  nrow <- dim(todrop)[1]
  for(i in 1:nrow){
    idx <- apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x == todrop[i, ]))
    df <- df[!idx, ]
  }
  return(df)
}

qq <- droprows_1(df, 1, 2, 3)
```

thank you

Comment: This isn't clear at all to be honest. What would you expect to result given your fake data?

Comment: I would like the counties containing a missing year to be removed from the data set entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To drop county's with a single missing value, use:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(county) %>% filter( !any(is.nan(yield)))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is easy in `data.table`. I don't exactly follow your example, but this sample data gets at what I think you're looking for:

```
N = 20000L
DT = data.table(
  state = sample(letters, size = N, replace = TRUE),
  county = sample(20L, size=N, replace = TRUE),
  year = rep(1981:2000, length.out = N),
  var = rnorm(N),
  key = c("state", "county", "year")
)

# Duplicated a bunch of state/year combinations
DT = unique(DT, by = c("state", "county", "year"))
```

Now, to your questions. I'll go step-by-step in case you're new to `data.table`; the last line is all you really need.

```
# This will count the number of years for each state/county combination:
DT[ , .N, by = .(state, county)]

# To focus on only those combinations which appear for every year
# (in my example there are 20 years)
# (also simultaneously drop the N column since we know every N is 20)
DT[ , .N, by = .(state, county)][N==20L, !"N"]

# The grande finale: reduce your data set to
# ONLY those combinations with full support:
full_data = DT[.(DT[ , .N, by = .(state, county)][N==20L, !"N"])]
```

Note that the last step *requires* that we set the keys of `DT` to `state` and `county`, in that order, which can be done with `setkey(DT, state, county)`. If you're not familiar with `data.table` notation, I recommend [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) page and in particular [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) vignette.

---

Edit: Just saw that you may be storing `NA` values for `year`, which case you should adjust the code to get out of counting `NA`s:

```
full_data = DT[.(DT[!is.na(year), .N, by = .(state, county)][N==20L, !"N"])]
```